# How can I pass a value from a Plone content schema field into a JQuery function?

Tags: jquery, plone

I have a Plone Dexterity custom type object that uses a JQuery function to control behavior. In the custom type, I have fields to allow the user to set parameters for the behavior (in this case a simple RSS feed) when they edit the content object.

Currently I have the function parameter values hard-coded directly into the JQuery function. I would like to be able to have the values from the custom type fields when edited and pass them into my JQuery function (example below).

How can I do that?

Dexterity Fields:

```
<field name="item_url" type="zope.schema.TextLine">
    <title>rss feed url</title>
    <description />
    <required />
</field>
<field name="item_count" type="zope.schema.TextLine">
    <title>item display number</title>
    <description />
    <required />
</field>
<field name="item_desc" type="zope.schema.Bool">
    <title>enable item description</title>
    <description />
    <required />
    <default>True</default>
    <form:widget type="z3c.form.browser.checkbox.SingleCheckBoxFieldWidget"/>
</field>
```

JQuery Function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#divRss').FeedEk({
        FeedUrl: '[item_url]',
        MaxCount: [item_count],
        ShowDesc: [item_desc],
    });
});
```

The JQuery looks for a specific object ID (in this case 'divRss') in my HTML code and writes out the code to generate the feed content. So in my template view file, it looks like this:

```
<div id="tabs-feed-widget-patients" class="easytabs tab-container">

        <div id="divRss" />

</div>
```

Comment: Do you have a custom default view for your content type? In this case you could add some `data-` attributes to the view, which holds the config. Now you could access them by `$('SELECTOR').data()` and use them in your JS snipped.

Comment: I do have a custom view for my content type. I am calling the jquery function from the .pt file. So how would that look in the jquery function code in my .pt file?

Comment: I added an answer...

Comment: I have edited my question to include the actual template code that the JQuery function looks for. The JQuery generates the feed code dynamically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have a custom view Page Template for your type, you could achieve this by add `data` attributes in your view.

I assume you have something like the following in your Page Template.

```xml
<div class="divRss">
    <div tal:content="context/item_url">Item url</div>
    <div tal:content="context/item_count">Item count</div>
    <div tal:content="context/item_desc">Item desc</div>
</div>
```

You can extend this by data attributes, you can also put theme somewhere else in the template (or hide them)

```xml
<div class="divRss">
    <div tal:define="url context/item_url"
         tal:attributes="data-url url"
         tal:content="url">Item url</div>

    <div tal:define="count context/item_count"
         tal:attributes="data-count count"
         tal:content="count">Item count</div>

    <div tal:define="desc context/item_desc"
         tal:attributes="data-desc desc"
         tal:content="desc">Item desc</div>

</div>
```

Your JS code may look like...

```javascript
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#divRss').FeedEk({
        FeedUrl: $('#divRss div').eq(0).data('url'),
        MaxCount: $('#divRss div').eq(1).data('count'),
        ShowDesc: $('#divRss div').eq(2).data('desc'),
    });
});
```

Well the implementation can be improved :-)
But this should point in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my original question and added the actual code snippet if the DIV block that calls the JQuery function above. I am unsure if that changes the logic or structure of your answer.

Comment: I got your solution to work with some modifications. If I send you the code I used, could you update your answer so I can accept it? It worked BEAUTIFULLY. Thank you very much.